# Do covariant functors preserve direct sums?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

Suppose $T$ is a covariant functor from the category **$R$-mod** to **Ab** (the category of abelian groups)

> Is is necessary that $T(B \oplus C) \cong T(B) \oplus T(C) $ ?

Does the answer change if we assume that the functor is left exact ?

I am trying to prove that left exact covariant preserves pullbacks and need this there. Thanks

Comment: An additive functor preserves finite direct sums.

Comment: @egreg yes, but the functor here is not given to be additive. So may be I should have asked : suppose a covariant functor preserves all direct sums, it is true that it is additive ?

Comment: Yes, it's additive. The sum of morphisms can be defined by using biproducts and preserving biproducts implies additivity.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, so the solution to the original question reduces to finding a functor which is not additive. But then is it true that every left exact functor (not necessarily additive) necessarily preserve pullbacks ?

Comment: I'm asking what “left exact” means for non additive functors.

Comment: @egreg Sorry if I am making some silly mistake, I am a beginner. A functor $T$ is left exact if for every exact sequence $ 0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ the sequence $ 0 \to T(A) \to T(B) \to T(C) $ is exact and a functor is additive if $T(f+g)=T(f)+T(g)$

Comment: A non additive functor need not take $0$ to $0$.

Comment: @egreg OK. Thank you so much. Now I understand the mistake I was making. We can talk about exactness only if the functor is additive

Comment: @user90041, how did you end up proving the original question: left exact covariant functor preserves pullbacks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In an additive category (in particular abelian), direct sums can be characterized by the existence of certain morphisms. So, if $A$ and $B$ are objects in the additive category and $C$ is another object, then $C$ is the coproduct and the product of $A$ and $B$ if and only if there are morphisms
\begin{align}
i_A\colon A&\to C\\
i_B\colon B&\to C\\
p_A\colon C&\to A\\
p_B\colon C&\to B
\end{align}
such that
$$
p_Ai_A=1_A,\quad
p_Bi_B=1_B,\quad
i_Ap_A+i_Bp_B=1_C
$$
Therefore, any additive functor preserves finite coproducts (and products, since they coincide).

Also, a functor between additive categories is additive if and only if it preserves finite coproducts. See Mac Lane's “Categories for the working mathematician”.

Comment: See http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/ for a discussion as well.